# $A$ is compact if and only if $e^{itA}-I$ is compact for all $t$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space, $A\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ is self adjoint, and define $U(t)=e^{itA}$. Show that $U(t)-I$ is compact for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $A$ is compact.

One direction is relatively straightforward: if $A$ is compact, write
$$
U(t)-I=A\big(itI+\frac{(it)^2}{2!}A+\frac{(it)^3}{3!}A^2+\dots\big),
$$
from which it is apparent that $U(t)-I$ is itself compact. However, I am having trouble with the other direction. One notes that as $A$ is self adjoint, $U(t)$ is unitary, but I am not sure where to head from here. I have also attempted to apply the spectral theorem, but to no avail. A hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Express $A$ as the derivative of $U$ at $t=0$ and use that limit of compact is compact.

Comment: Try the contrapositive so you are still moving the proof in the same direction i.e. if A were noncompact, does that guarantee $e^{itA}-I$ is noncompact?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I've tried this, so non compactness gives me a bounded sequence with no convergence subsequence in the image, but this doesn't translate nicely to $U(t)-I$...

Comment: Also, I'm trying to think through both of these suggested approaches, and don't see how the assumption that $A$ is self adjoint is being applied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function $U:\mathbb{R}\to L(H)$ by $U(t)=e^{itA}$. Note that $U$ is differentiable, in the sense that the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{U(t+h)-U(t)}{h}$ exists in $L(H)$ for all $t$. Denote the derivative by $U'(t)$ as usual and note that $U'(t)=iAU(t)$ for all $t$. If any of the claims here are unclear to you, check out Murphy's book, p.11-12.

You have already handled one direction. For the other, assume that $U(t)-I$ is compact for all $t$. Let $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $h>0$. Then
$$\frac{U(t+h)-U(t)}{h}=\frac{(U(t+h)-I)-(U(t)-I)}{h}$$
which is a compact operator, as a linear combination of compacts. Since the compact operators form a closed set, we can take the limit as $h\to0^+$ and deduce that $U'(t)$ is also compact. This is true for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

But $U'(0)=iAU(0)=iA$, so $iA$ is compact and therefore $A$ is compact.

Comment: This seems correct, but you do not use the assumption that $A$ is self adjoint, or that $U(t)-I$ is compact for all $t$ (you really only need a neighborhood of $0$)... I wonder if there's a different solution which the question intended... Regardless, nice answer!

Comment: @RomainS I don't think that it is necessary for A to be self adjoint. And yes, it suffices dor $U(t)-I$ to be compact around 0 for this to work. But then you conclude that A is compact so $U(t)-I$ is compat for all t, as you did in your post.